# How to carry out conditional font installation on Vista Business using NSIS?

Tags: nsis

i am using NSIS for my app setup. I need to carry out conditional installation of Font files. I've tried using the following piece of script(for arial and verdana):-

```
IfFileExists "$FONTS\arial.ttf" Continue InstallFont

InstallFont:
  SetOutPath "$FONTS"
  File "arial.ttf"

Continue:
  # Continue in installation...
```

This works on MS XP(both for arial and verdana), but does not on my MS Vista Business(I deleted verdana from fonts folder prior to running my installation). But some how the fonts does not get installed on Vista. Please help!!.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing anything from the code you have posted?

I haven't tested NSIS for installing fonts on XP but the code you have above would not work for Vista (or at least, would not work for Windows 7)

Have a look at the [Register_Fonts](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Register_Fonts) and [Advanced_Font_Installation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Advanced_Font_Installation) scripts. They should install your fonts as needed.

Using these scripts your code NSIS script should look something like this (I've left out the conditional logic but that should work just fine):

```
!include FontRegAdv.nsh
!include FontName.nsh

!define FontBackup Reg\key\To\Backup\Fonts\entries\To

  StrCpy $FONT_DIR $FONTS

  !insertmacro InstallTTF 'arial.TTF'

  SendMessage ${HWND_BROADCAST} ${WM_FONTCHANGE} 0 0 /TIMEOUT=5000
SectionEnd
```

For my own project I'm using the Unicode build of NSIS. This means I can't use the above scripts so I instead use basic registry and winapi functions (which is what the scripts above do under the covers). An example of my code is below:

```
Section InstallFont

    SetOutPath "$FONTS"
    File "arial.ttf"

    ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" "CurrentVersion"
    IfErrors Win9x WinNT

    Win9x:
        StrCpy $FONTREGKEY "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Fonts"
        Goto RegFont

    WinNT:
        StrCpy $FONTREGKEY "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts"
        Goto RegFont

    RegFont:
        ClearErrors

    System::Call "gdi32::AddFontResource(t 'arial.ttf')"       

    Push 'arial.ttf'
    Call GetFontName
    Pop $R0

    ${If} $R0 != 'error'
        WriteRegStr HKLM '$FONTREGKEY' '$R0 (TrueType)' 'arial.ttf'
    ${Else}
        System::Call "gdi32::RemoveFontResource(t 'arial.ttf')"
    ${EndIf}

SectionEnd

Function GetFontName
  Exch $R0
  Push $R1
  Push $R2

  System::Call *(i${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN})i.R1
  System::Alloc ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}
  Pop $R2
  System::Call gdi32::GetFontResourceInfoW(wR0,iR1,iR2,i1)i.R0
  ${If} $R0 == 0
    StrCpy $R0 error
  ${Else}
    System::Call *$R2(&w${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}.R0)
  ${EndIf}
  System::Free $R1
  System::Free $R2

  Pop $R2
  Pop $R1
  Exch $R0
FunctionEnd
```